# Errors in prediction on rolling window in R with MSGARCH

Tags: r

I'm using MSGARCH to get volatility forecasts based on rolling window.

However, when fitting forecasts on rolling window I get the following error messages:

`Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

In addition:

`Warning messages: 1: In sqrt(diag(mSandwitch)) : NaNs produced`

And zero values starting from some point of forecasted output.

I've tried to change the range of the data used, but it only leads to zeroes starting from a different point.
If I change the number of day-ahead prediction there will be NAs and zeroes in forecasted output.
I've also changed `FitML` to `FitMCMC`, and get no errors, however the forecasted output mostly included large numbers like 5e+37, which is quite unrealistic for volatility and my data.
Moreover, if I forecast the same model without loop for n-day ahead forecast (n=1, 50, 400,..), there will be no problem.
If I use randomly generated data instead of mine with `runif` function `(min=-1,max=1)`, the problem stays the same.

```
#Create the forecasts vector to store the predictions
windowLength = 100
foreLength<-365
MSforecasts <- vector(length=foreLength)

for (d in 1:foreLength) {
  # Obtain the rolling window 
  RollingWindow = window(FileAllData$Returns, start=(6850+d), end=(6850+windowLength+d))
  MSmodel<-CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH", "gjrGARCH", "eGARCH")),
                  distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("snorm", "std", "sged")),
                  switch.spec = list(do.mix = FALSE))
  MSmodel_est<-FitML(spec = MSmodel, data=RollingWindow)

  #Forecasting
  MSforecast<-predict(MSmodel_est, nahead = 1)
  MSforecasts[d]<-MSforecast$vol
}
MSforecasts
```

How could my code be modified, so it produces the correct forecast values?

P.S. I'm new to SO, so guide me if there's any additional information I could provide to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Error would have to be in the method "window" that accept as argument the date of time series. Try in the following way:

```
Create the forecasts vector to store the predictions
windowLength = 100
foreLength<-365
MSforecasts <- vector(length=foreLength)

for (d in 1:foreLength) {
  # Obtain the rolling window 
  RollingWindow = FileAllData$Returns[(6850+d):(6850+windowLength+d)] 
  MSmodel<-CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH", "gjrGARCH", "eGARCH")),
                  distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("snorm", "std", "sged")),
                  switch.spec = list(do.mix = FALSE))
  MSmodel_est<-FitML(spec = MSmodel, data=RollingWindow)

  #Forecasting
  MSforecast<-predict(MSmodel_est, nahead = 1)
  MSforecasts[d]<-MSforecast$vol
}
MSforecasts
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've just tried what you suggested, but the result remained the same

Comment: than there is an error in your FileAllData$Returns because I have not problem to run that code with my dataset. Length of FileAllData$Returns is 6850+ foreLength+ windowLength?

Comment: The length is 7973, and it really seems that the code depends on a dataset, because for the range [(6850):(6850+windowLength)] it works fine but if fit the model for [(6850+40):(6850+40+windowLength)] there errors arise. But I do not understand why it happens, as the whole data is usual returns